# How to configure Docker for windows to push using hosts file for repository

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to push a container from my local dev box to a remote private repository whose hostname is set in my Windows host file.  When I push I get this:

```
docker push docker:5000/m2
The push refers to a repository [docker:5000/m2]
Put http://docker:5000/v1/repositories/m2/: dial tcp: lookup docker on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host
```

If I do a curl -vvv on the URL using babun I get this:

```
curl -vvv http://docker:5000/v1/repositories/m2/
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x20048188; line 1034 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
*   Trying 192.168.1.8...
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x20048188; line 1087 (connection #0)
* Connected to docker (192.168.1.8) port 5000 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => DO handle 0x20048188; line 1229 (connection #0)
> GET /v1/repositories/m2/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US))
> Host: docker:5000
> Accept: */*
>
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x20048188; line 1314 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x20048188; line 1441 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x20048188; line 1454 (connection #0)
* Increasing bytecount by 7 from hbuflen

* nread <= 0, server closed connection, bailing
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x20048188; line 1626 (connection #0)
* Connection #0 to host docker left intact
* Expire cleared
```

Since I'm getting the error message locally, but not when I use curl, and given the error message, it seems like my local Windows docker instance is not resolving to the `docker` hostname.

Comment: Are you behind a VPN?

Comment: I have a VPN on the remote machine.  But I can do inbound HTTP, SSH, and the like without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Docker does the push on the remote docker daemon, not the local docker client, which means the DNS resolution needs to work on that system. This also includes any proxy settings. There was also a recent bug that at least affected Docker for Mac, possibly also Windows too, where it was not using the local DNS server. I believe that's been fixed in 1.13.1, but I already worked around that by adding the entries I needed into the /etc/hosts file (I believe windows still puts this under system32\drivers\etc).

Note that after you change DNS settings on the Windows host to get name resolution working, you'll likely need to restart the docker daemon to get the embedded VM to restart with these changes.

Comment: It works on the CLI on Windows (I'm using Babun which edits the system32/etc/hosts file) for other programs.  Telnet, for example, works.

Comment: I should also note that when I use tcpdump on the repository system I see the telnet traffic, but I don't see anything from the docker client.

Comment: The command runs on the server, not the client, so you shouldn't see any client traffic. Anything that modifies the /etc/hosts file after the docker vm has started won't be seen by the vm, you need to bounce the docker vm for that change to be picked up.

Comment: So I build a container on my local desktop, and pushing it to my remote repository should result in no traffic?

Comment: You don't build images on the docker client, you build them on the docker engine. The client is a frontend for the REST interface, no images are stored there.

Comment: Fine, but that misses the point I'm trying to work through.  I initiate a push on my local instance and it can't get to my remote instance.

Comment: Yes, which I've answered above. It's not clear from your comments that you've made any attempts to follow any of the given advice. At the very least, details on what version of Docker you are running, the DNS and /etc/hosts file settings on the parent OS, and whether you've restarted the docker service (VM) since the last network change.

Comment: Yes.  Several times.  Version: 1.13.1.